# how to connect codeigniter with mySqlworkbench

Tags: codeigniter, mysql-workbench

I'm novice to php programming and currently developing a inventory control system as my assignment. I want to use Codeigniter and My SqlWorkbench. I want to know how to connect those two ? How to call SqlWorkbench DB in Codeigniter ? Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You don't understand the basics.

MySQL Workbench is a [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system), not a database. It is an interface to control databases, in this case MySQL databases. There are alternatives, like phpMyAdmin, chive, HeidiSQL (Windows desktop application) and plenty of others.

You don't connect CodeIgniter and Workbench in any way, they both connect to MySQL database which is standalone service running on the server.

The fastest way to get up running is to setup [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html), [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or their alternatives on your PC, that way you will have everything you need to get started - Apache, PHP and MySQL. After that you start your MySQL Workbench and can control the contents and structure of any databases and their tables you've created and will be using in MySQL.

I can suggest, that if you ask such a question, you don't know the basics of programming in PHP and CodeIgniter is far off your level, so I suggest you get started with writing basic application in pure PHP with MySQL, because you will not understand how to manipulate things in CodeIgniter and will only waste your time. After you get more familiar and comfortable with these things, you may move to CodeIgniter or other frameworks.